# automate move mouse in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ui-automation

I'm interested in a reliable way to move the mouse across html, canvas or iframe elements to a given set of coordinates. The browser (chrome and firefox) will be run under a testing driver with the web security options disabled, so doing `$('iframe').contents().find()`  will **not** result in an cross-site security error.

`selenium` has something that seems to work quite good, which is `move_by_offset`. I'm working with that API, but it would make my life so much easier if there was a javascript code that could produce the same end result.

I've search for js code snippets, but most examples I've seen only move to given elements (in the case of firefox, to the center of the element bounding box)

Comment: So I presume this is meant for an internal site?

Comment: I haven't covered anything regarding this before, but as you mention being able to move to elements, why not make a 1x1 fixed transparent div and move that around the screen, then move the mouse to it?

Comment: this is for internal company sites only, yes

Comment: we cannot modify the application pages during testing. We can only interact via selenium or via the javascripts in content scripts and background in a chrome testing extension